# Problema con los CORS en Laravel y Angular

Tags: laravel, angular, servidor, cors

os comento el problema tengo. He desarollado una API rest Laravel con Angular.

- Laravel: --> **5.7 ***
- Angular: --> **8.2.9**
- __________Angular CLI: **8.3.8**

El proyecto esta separado por 2 carpetas cada una con su diferente tecnología.

Una vez acabado el proyecto, lo pase a producción con el servidor **IONOS**.

Pero me apareció este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al investigar me encontré con varias soluciones (pero ninguna me funciono):

### 1º -- Crear un Subdominio

1. Subí el proyecto Laravel a una carpeta
2. Crea un Subdominio en **IONOS**
3. Crear el subdominio que apunte a la carpeta public de Laravel
4. Modificar la variable **global** de Angular para que coincida con el Subdominio.

### 2º -- Middleware

//Creamos un middleware

```
->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*’)
->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS’);
```

//ingresamos al Kernel

```
'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
```

//Agregamos a las rutas

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function(){
    //aqui van todas las rutas que necesitan CORS
});
```

Os dejo el enlace de donde saque la infoamción, por si a alguien le sirve
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KvldwGjCg5M&t=185s

### 3º -- Fruitcake

Instalando

```
composer require fruitcake/laravel-cors
```

Y luego realizando tosa las configuraciones

Enlace:
https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors

---

## Estado actual

**Middleware**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request);
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*’)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS’);

    }
}
```

**Kernel**

```
protected $middleware = [
      ....
      \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class, 
    ];

protected $routeMiddleware = [
        .....
        'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
    ];
```

**cors.php --- *config***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Rutas**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

### Comunicación con Angular

La comunicación hacia es Backend (Laravel), la realizo mediante servicios que son llamados desde los componentes. Aquí dejo un ejemplo:

**Service**

```
@Injectable()
export class PostService{
    public url: string;

    constructor(
            private _http:HttpClient 
        ){
            this.url = global.url;
    }

getPost():Observable<any>{
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    return this._http.get(this.url + 'post' ,{headers:headers});
}
```

**Componente**

```
   getSubByCategory(id){
    this._categoryService.getSub(id).subscribe(
      response => {
        if(response.status == 'success'){
          this.subs = response.sub_category;
        }
        else{
          this._router.navigate(['/productos']);
        }

        },
      error =>{
        console.log(error);
      }
      )           
  }
```

Porfavor necesito ayuda, igualmente por lo que visto estas soluciones sueles ser efectivas. Espero que a alguien se sirva.

Comment: Angular es fronted... supongo que solo lo utilizas fronted y laravel(php) es el backend.., porque tener proyectos separados?. Independientemente de esa observación, todo lo que muestras aqui es solo laravel no muetras como accedes desde Angular, hiciste micro servicios o algo asi para la comunicacion entre tecnologias?

Comment: Tengo los proyectos separados por tema de seguridad y comodidad. En cuanto a como me comunico en Angular,  es mediante Servicios que llamo desde los componentes. Dejo ejemplos en la pregunta, muchas gracias por ayudarme.